# c# mailmessage include body description and html file

Tags: c#, mailmessage

how to include description first then just display the html file when send email??

### below are my current code

```
            string emailFrom =  "abc@hotmail.com";
            string emailTo = "test@company.com.my";
            string emailSubject = "e-Receipt";
            string emailDescription = "Dear Customer, \n Attached is your e-Receipt. Thank You.";

            StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("C:/file/invoice.html");
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(emailFrom, emailTo, emailSubject, reader.ReadToEnd());
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            Attachment data = new Attachment(path+filename, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
            ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
            disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(path + filename);
            disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(path + filename);
            disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(path + filename);
            message.Attachments.Add(data);
```

### expected result email content

https://ibb.co/cEFbN7

Comment: I think you can't control the attachment display, recipient SMTP server will handle the attachment and if it should be displayed at all. about html code, if you have any CSS in it it should be hard-coded in each tag you can't use classes, style tags etc. at least this is how it was last time I checked...

Comment: Hi, i have updated the expected result with image, please check again.

Comment: An email message only has one body. If you expect your message and the contents of a file to be displayed in the message then you have to combine them into a single `String` and make that the body of the message. That means that your message has to be valid HTML too. As for the attachment, as suggested, that's up to the recipient's mail client.

Comment: You don't add the emailDescription string to the content

Comment: Also, you should use `Path.Combine` to combine multiple partial paths.

Comment: @jmcilhinney hi hinney, could you show a way how to combine them ?

Comment: You're really asking me to show you how to combine two `Strings` into one? Not happening.